# question about the partial sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

How can I interpret Series that starts from an index $k=m$ with $k \neq 1$ as a sequence of partial sums, i.e. how do i interpret $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}b_k$? Do we define $a_n:=0$ for all $n < m$ and $a_n:= \sum_{k=m}^{\infty}b_k$ for $n \geq m$ or can we make a shift like $a_n:=\sum_{k=m}^{(n-1)+m}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

remark: $\mathbb{N}={1,2,3,\dots}$ without $0$.

Comment: I think the answer is it doesn't really matter.

Comment: In your first sentence, I assume $k \neq 1$ is supposed to be $m \neq 1.$ Also, I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Use whatever you wish, as long as what you write corresponds to what you intend to say. Also, I think your question is made overly complicated by trying to consider a general situation. I think it would be better to focus on exactly what it is you are dealing with, and then explicitly give two (or more) descriptions that you're unsure about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by considering the sequence of partial sums related to the given formal series:
\begin{align*}
S_{N} = \sum_{k=m}^{N}b_{k}
\end{align*}

Consequently, when $S_{N}$ converges, we denote it by the expression
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}b_{n} = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}S_{N} = L
\end{align*}

Precisely speaking, it means that, for every postive real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $M\geq m$ such that
\begin{align*}
n \geq M \Longrightarrow |S_{n} - L| = \left|\sum_{k=m}^{n}b_{k} - L\right| \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Since the initial values of the sequence of partial sums do not influence its convergence (although it changes its sum if it converges), there is no problem in starting at $k = m$ instead of $k = 1$.